# angular 2 material keyup.enter does not fire at all

Tags: angular, angular-material, keyup

I am trying to hit enter key to press a button on my login form. However it does not. The code looks like:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="doLogin()" (keyup.enter)="doLogin()">
    Sign In
  </button>
</div>
```

I have no idea why it is not firing. No error in console and angular documentation does not indicate any special requirement for it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the controls are in a form, the `ngSubmit` event will be triggered when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. To also trigger the event by clicking the button, you should remove the attribute `type="button"`. The default type is `type="submit"` when the button is in a form.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onNgSubmit()">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name" />
    <button mat-raised-button>Sign In</button>
  </div>    
</form>
```

```
export class UserFormComponent {
  onNgSubmit() {
    // Proceed with login...
  }
}
```

You can test the code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-fwdg19).

Comment: the another issue was i did set name="username" but using [(ngModel)]

Comment: Wha if the button is a dialog button that is not inside a form ?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying keyup  on a **`button`**, button does not have that event, instead you should try on **`input`** of form

```
<form >
  <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="doLogin()" />
</form
```

**EDIT**

if you want to get this fired when submitting use

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="doLogin()">
```

Comment: what do you mean? button is not an input element

Comment: your above code doesnt work either i wrapped my login form around  <form (keyup.enter)="doLogin()">

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This works just fine for me. Hope it helps!

```
<form>
  <input type="text" (keyup.enter) = "doLogin($event)">
</form>
```

In your **component**:

```
doLogin(e){
 console.log(e);
}
```