# How to make a button, that is inside a dialog but not inside a form, respond to Enter key being pressed

Tags: angular

I need that a button inside a dialog responds to the `key.enter` event.

I have searched and all the examples are buttons that are inside a `<form>` which is not the case

Do I need to put the button inside a "dummy form" for this to work? can I do that without losing the current button style

This is what I have tried...

```html
<mat-dialog-actions class="buttons">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="onCancelClick()">
        {{data.cancel}}
    </button>
    <button class="action nonDefault" mat-button mat-dialog-close color="accent" class="action"
        (click)="cancelOrClose()" (keyup.enter)="cancelOrClose()">
        {{data.cancelOrClose}}
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Hitting enter with the dialog open does nothing

similar questions that I have found

[Angular 5 Button Submit On Enter Key Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129245/angular-5-button-submit-on-enter-key-press)

[angular 2 material keyup.enter does not fire at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613131/angular-2-material-keyup-enter-does-not-fire-at-all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `autofocus` and `(keyup.enter)` on the button so that it processes the key events

```html
<button class="action nonDefault" #btnFocus [autofocus]="btnFocus.focus()" mat-button
    (keyup.enter)="cancelOrClose()" (click)="cancelOrClose()" mat-dialog-close>
    {{data.cancelOrClose}}
</button>
```